# Converting Geojson with utm values to latlon (To display in Cesium)

Tags: geojson, utm, cesium

I have a GeoJson with coordinate fields which seem to be in UTM:

```
[3840346.36141685, 3270002.87814633]
```

My final goal is to be able to load them correctly using Cesium.
To do that, it seems I need to convert the coordinates to lat-lon.
What is the best way to do it? I couldn't find any quick one.

Comment: GeoJSON can only contain lon/lat coordinates, so you need to speak to your data supplier about a better format

Comment: See https://programmersought.com/article/45377329486/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PROJ4JS](http://proj4js.org/)

[Sample Code](https://github.com/3DGISKing/CesiumJsSamples/tree/master/Advanced/UTM)

```
 function utmToLatlon(easting, northing) {
     const utm = `+proj=utm +zone=${zoneNumber}`;
     const wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

     return proj4(utm, wgs84, [easting, northing]);
 }
```